# I tried this but it doesn't work, words are printed with no spaces and I get errors

Tags: amsmath, mathtools

[image: Output]

```
\[
 x^\lambda_p = \begin{dcases*}
        1  & if \lambda  is assigned to P\\
        0  & $Otherwise$
        \end{dcases*}
\]
```

Comment: Next time, maybe try to think of a more descriptive question title :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Be sure to use `$` in the right places (but not in the wrong places):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
 x^\lambda_p = \begin{dcases*}
        1  & if $\lambda$ is assigned to $p$ \\
        0  & otherwise
        \end{dcases*}
\]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

A general tip: if words are set in italics and spaces are being ignored, chances are you're in math mode when you don't want to be.